# How do I loop states with clock signal?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I need `en` to loop between 4 specific given states: 4'b0111 , 4'b1011, 4'b1101, and 4'b1110

This is my code so far

```
// enable pin cycle
    always_ff @(posedge clk) en <=
       4'b0111 ? 4'b1011 : 
       4'b1011 ? 4'b1101 : 
       4'b1101 ? 4'b1110 :
       4'b1110 ? 4'b0111 : en;
```

From what I can tell, through the hardware, it passes the first stage onto 4'b1011 then stops entirely.

This is most likely caused by the fact that it is a conditional operator; however, from what I understand, it should still loop.

How can I get this working?

And if it's not possible, what's a better way of doing this loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you need to compare `en` against all those values.

For example, you need to do something like:

```
(en == 4'b0111) ? 4'b1011 :
```

In your code, the first condition is `(4'b0111)`, which is always true.  So, `en` gets the value `4'b1011`.  `en` then remains at `4'b1011` on all subsequent clock edges because the first condition (`(4'b0111)`) always evaluates to true.  No other condition is ever evaluated.

You could continue to use the conditional operator, but I think the code would be a lot easier to understand using a `case`:

```
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
    case (en)
        4'b0111: en <= 4'b1011;
        4'b1011: en <= 4'b1101;
        4'b1101: en <= 4'b1110;
        4'b1110: en <= 4'b0111;       
        default: en <= 4'b0111;       
    endcase
end
```